# Element should have been "select" but was "div" getting an error in selenium

Tags: html, css, selenium

Here is the HTML code, i'm trying to select 'select customer' drop-down.

```
<div id="createTasksPopup_customerSelector" class="customerOrProjectSelector selectorWithPlaceholderContainer at-dropdown-list-btn-ct notSelected">
    <table id="ext-comp-1057" class="x-btn-wrap x-btn at-dropdown-list-btn x-btn-over x-btn-focus" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: auto;">
       <tbody>
             <tr id="ext-gen397" class=" x-btn-with-menu">
                  <td class="x-btn-left">
                      <td class="x-btn-center">
                          <em unselectable="on">
                              <button id="ext-gen391" class="x-btn-text" type="button">- Select Customer -</button>
                          </em>
                      </td>
                 <td class="x-btn-right">
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Image -**
[image]

Comment: what locator you are using, please complete your question

Comment: Is the ID element is auto-generated, I mean does it changes every time you load the page

Comment: Hi Gaurav, i'm using locator as selectCustomer_XPATH=//div[@id='createTasksPopup_customerSelector'] and ID element is not auto generated. I'm attaching new screen shots, please refer. Thanks

Comment: Also: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/36118/element-should-have-been-select-but-was-div-error/36119#36119

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception generally occurs when we use Select command to select dropdowns which are not built by using "select" tag.

You can try by using sendkeys to select dropdown, just give displayed text of option in sendkeys.

If above does not work, then go for click on dropdown and again click on required option.

If it is auto complete dropdown, then click on that dropdown input box and go for senkeys char by char with small sleep, so that required option will be displayed.

Comment: Hi Murali, i'm trying to select 'ALL ACTIVE CUSTOMER' from drop-down below the code i'm using but the dropdown-value not selecting.

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath(ObjRepoProp.getProperty("selectCustomer_XPATH"))).click();
  Thread.sleep(5000);
   Actions act = new Actions(driver);
    act.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).perform();

Answer (score 2):

First check that:

Drop down in your UI/FrontEnd is using "select" method or not ?

And if not then use below snippet that will click in drop down and select value.

```
WebElement selectMyElement = driver.findElement(this.getObject(By.Id("Id of Your DropDown"))); 
selectMyElement.click();

Actions keyDown = new Actions(driver);
keyDown.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.DOWN, Keys.DOWN)).perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement selectMyElement = driver.findElement(this.getObject(By.Id("Id of Your DropDown"))); 
selectMyElement.click();

Actions keyDown = new Actions(driver);
keyDown.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.DOWN, Keys.DOWN)).perform();
```

Above worked for me